# Wordpress Shortcode wrap around div

Tags: templates, shortcode

Is there a way to wrap a wordpress shortcode around a div in a template file?
Here is my code:

```
<div id="subscription">
<?php do_shortcode('[subscribe]');?>
<p>This is subscription text</p>
</div>
```

I've also tried

```
<div id="subscription">
<?php do_shortcode('[subscribe]');?>
<p>This is subscription text</p>
<?php do_shortcode('[/subscribe]');?>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you need to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by template file you mean a php file in the themes folder, you can call [do_shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) to have the shortcode processor do its magic on your div.

EDIT: not entirely sure I understand what you want, but you could try this:

```
<div id="subscription">
<?php do_shortcode('[subscribe]'.call_php_function().'[/subscribe]');?>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I meant, and I've tried to insert it in the div but I dont think I'm doing it right. I'll past the code above. Thanks @Femi

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure the above code should be

```
<?php do_shortcode('[subscribe]<p>This is the subscription text</p>[/subscribe]'); ?>
```

Then you can use the content in the shortcode function like so:

```
<?php
function subscribe_shortcode($atts, $content = '', $code = NULL) {

return '<div id="whatever-etc">'.$content.'</div>';
}
add_shortcode('subscribe', 'subscribe_shortcode');

?>
```

The above would output:

```
<div id="whatever-etc">
<p>This is the subscription text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Frank Martin! This is what I was also thinking, but the problem is the real code that Im using has some Php inside of my subscription div. is there a way that I could work with this?

Comment: This code is being used to hide and show content for premium users on a website. If they are logged in as a premium member it will show the content that is inside of the shortcode, otherwise it will say they can purchase it

Comment: If it's in the template file is there any need for the shortcode at all? Can't you just put a conditional statement around the content?

Comment: That was my next option, but the plugin that I'm using to show and hide content targets what to hide with a shortcode. I know its pretty dumb but its normally used to hide content that is written within wordpress but for my case its different. Would you have an idea of how I could use a conditional for this?

Comment: To be honest I don't think I'm entirely clear on what you need to achieve.

Comment: i tried this shortcode, but my output is <div id="whatever-src"></div>This is the subscription text, any thoughts why the text is outputting outside of the div i have it wrapped in in the shortcode?